# Evaluating $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have this series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n=1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+...+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}+...$$

The sum of the first N terms is:
$$S_N=\sum_{n=1}^N s_n=1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+...+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$$

It converges for Leibniz's test to a certain values
$$\sigma=\sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n=\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} S_N$$

I want to proof that $S_N \ge\frac{1}{2}$ and then $\sigma \ge\frac{1}{2}$ (in my book the author says that it is possible , but he doesn't show that)

$P(1)$ is true (because $s_1=1\ge \frac{1}{2}$).

We suppose that $P(N)$ is true (because $s_N\ge \frac{1}{2}$) and we have to proof that for $N+1$.
 $$S_{N+1}=\sum_{n=1}^N s_n+\frac{(-1)^{N+2}}{N+1}=S_N+\frac{(-1)^{N+2}}{N+1} \ge \frac{1}{2}+\frac{(-1)^{N+2}}{N+1}= \frac{N+1+2(-1)^{N+2}}{2*(N+1)}
$$
If n is even $\frac{N+3}{2*(N+1)} \ge \frac {1}{2}$
If n is odd  $\frac{N-1}{2*(N+1)} \le \frac {1}{2}$
where am I wrong?

Comment: Pair two consecutive terms starting with $n=1$ and $n=2$.  Note that all of the following pairs are greater than $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that

$$S_{2N}=\sum_{n=1}^{2N}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^N \left(\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}\right)$$

and

$$S_{2N+1}=\sum_{n=1}^{2N+1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^N \left(\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}\right)+\frac1{2N+1}$$

Comment: do you consider for $P(1):S_2 \ge  \frac{1}{2}$,  for $P(N):S_{2N}\ge  \frac{1}{2}$, and for $P(N+1):S_{2(N+1)}\ge  \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Anne, you may take $P(1)$ that $S_2=1/2$.  Then, assume for $P(2N)>\frac12$ using the first line in the post herein.  Finally, note that $S(2N+1)>S(2N)$.

Comment: I didn't understand the form for $S_{  2N}$

Comment: Anne, $S_{2N}$ sums the series from $1$ to an even number $2N$.  This is identical to summing the pairs of consecutive odd and even terms.